# vb.net how to flatten 3 dimensional array into single dimension

Tags: arrays, vb.net

My code

```
Dim b()()() As Byte = New Byte(1)()() {New Byte()() {New Byte() {1, 2, 3}, New Byte() {4, 5, 6, 7}}, 
                                       New Byte()() {New Byte() {1, 2, 3}, New Byte() {4, 5, 6, 7}}}
' Put all arays into a single array.
Dim flatten As Byte() = b.SelectMany((Function(x) x) x).ToArray()
```

........gets this error:

> Value of type 'Byte()()' cannot be converted to 'Byte()' because 'Byte()' is not derived from 'Byte'.

Here's the example of how to do it with 2 dimensions, that I got from another guy on StackO.

```
Dim a()() As Byte = New Byte(1)() {New Byte() {1, 2, 3}, New Byte() {4, 5, 6, 7}}
' Put all arays into a single array.
Dim flatten As Byte() = a.SelectMany(Function(x) x).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add another `SelectMany`, like this.

```
Dim flatten As Byte() = b.SelectMany(Function(x) x.SelectMany(Function(y) y)).ToArray()
```

Comment: @Doug Null - Did that answer your question?

Comment: @Doug Null - Did not hear from you.